# Generate personal access token from GitHub API via C# in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, rest, github, xamarin, github-api

I am developing mobile GitHub client and I need to generate personal access token from code, not from github website. It is Xamarin.Forms project so it is pcl and c#. I know there is a way because this https://github.com/jonan/ForkHub app doing this. Here is it done with python : http://kinto.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/authentication-github.html
How I can do that?

Comment: Could you use OAuth to generate one instead https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Comment: I can Autorize my app and use it for one account. But it dont suit for two reasons:
1) I want to provide access for different accounts in different time.
2) It is open source app so I cant store my client id and secret in code.
I need exactly generate personal access token and store it in android account manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didnt see simple words, that client id and secret are not require, so I used https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization and all works fine.